# clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mern, nodemon

I don't understand what the problem is with the code, following the MERN guide from YouTube. Many thanks to anyone who will help.
[posts.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L86Fk.png)

[posts.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCiQ6.png)

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWKdr.png)
[terminal:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZg3A.png)

Comment: Please, paste the code and logs into your question as text. A link to the video you mentioned (with a timestamp marker if needed) could also make it easier to answer the question.

Comment: Your question must be self contained without depending on external resources. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example